# Ant failed with error "Failed to locateorg.apache.tools.ant.Main" in centos5.11

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, build, centos

Unable to execute ant. it was working fine. but suddenly started throwing an error. can someone please help. Checked the environment variables and everything seems to be fine.

```
[root@usbossbuild ~]# ant -version
Failed to locateorg.apache.tools.ant.Main
ant.home: /hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4
Classpath: /hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/activation.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-antlr.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-oro.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-resolver.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-commons-logging.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-commons-net.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-jai.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-javamail.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-jdepend.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-jmf.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-jsch.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-junit.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-junit4.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-netrexx.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-swing.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-testutil.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/jsch-0.1.50.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/mail.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ojdbc6.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/surround.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/xmltask.jar:/hidapp_build/u01/jdk_home/lib/tools.jar
Launcher JAR: /hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant-launcher.jar
Launcher Directory: /hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib
```

Below are environment variables which required for ANT

```
[root@usbossbuild ~]# echo $ANT_HOME
/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4

[root@usbossbuild ~]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/hidapp_build/u01/jdk_home

[root@usbossbuild ~]# which java
/hidapp_build/u01/jdk_home/bin/java

[root@usbossbuild ~]# java -version
java version "1.6.0_38"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode)

[root@usbossbuild ~]# ls -lrt /hidapp_build/u01/jdk_home/lib/tools.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 oracle build 12627443 May  3  2013 /hidapp_build/u01/jdk_home/lib/tools.jar
```

Below are output from jenkins. in this i see it is searching in different path /usr/lib/jvm. i dont know why.

```
[SIS_Dev_MA_2.3_Onboarding_scm_workaround] $ /hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/bin/ant -file sis_onboard_scmworkaround.xml download
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.34.x86_64/lib/tools.jar
```

Comment: `org.apache.tools.ant.Main` should live in a file named `ant.jar` under `$ANT_HOME/lib`. In your case, `$ANT_HOME` is `/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4`. However, `ant.jar` is missing in your `Classpath:`.  So, does `/hidapp_build/u01/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant.jar` exist?

Comment: Thanks alot @ChadNouis. Yes. ant.jar is missed in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue like this because my /etc/profile.d/ant.sh file had Windows-style line endings instead of UNIX style.  You can verify this if you try "cd $ANT_HOME" and it shows a messed up error message like ": No such file or directory1.9.4".